# Select All Checkboxes - Toggle On and Off

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have a table with a checkbox in the first column - when checked this performs an AJAX script that updates a PHP session variable with the selected values. I also have a check box at the top of the first column to allow the user to select all items in the table and perform an AJAX script.

I have this working for the "select all when not checked" state, i.e. when the page first loads. I now need to add the reverse state - unchecking all checkboxes on the page.

Here's how my table looks and the script that runs when you click the checkbox in the table header:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.select-all').on('click', function() {
    var values = []; // will contain all checkbox values that you can send via ajax
    $('table > tbody input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i, el) {
      $(el).prop('checked', true);
      values.push(el.value);
    });
    var productIDs = values.join();;
    // Create a reference to $(this) here:
    $this = $(this);
    $.post('productSelections.php', {
      type: 'updateSelections',
      productIDs: productIDs,
      selectionType: 'single'
    }, function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      if (data.error) {
        var ajaxError = (data.text);
        var errorAlert = 'There was an error updating the Product Selections Selections - ' + ajaxError;
        $this.closest('td').addClass("danger");
        //display AJAX error details
        $("#updateSelectionsErrorMessage").html(errorAlert);
        $("#updateSelectionsError").show();
        return; // stop executing this function any further
      } else {
        $this.closest('td').addClass("success")
        $this.closest('td').removeClass("danger");
      }

    }).fail(function(xhr) {
      var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
      var ajaxError = 'There was an error updating the Product Selections - AJAX request error. HTTP Status: ' + httpStatus + '. Please contact Apple Business Operations';
      $this.closest('td').addClass("danger");
      $("#updateSelectionsErrorMessage").html(ajaxError);
      $("#updateSelectionsError").show();
      $this.attr('checked', false); // Unchecks it
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th><input type="checkbox" class="select-all checkbox" name="select-all" /></th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Product ID</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Description</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="" id="85799">
      <td id="AT36288"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36288" /></td>
      <td>AT36288</td>
      <td>Apples</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85800">
      <td id="AT36289"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36289" /></td>
      <td>AT36289</td>
      <td>Bananas</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85801">
      <td id="AT36290"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36290" /></td>
      <td>AT36290</td>
      <td>Oranges</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85803">
      <td id="AT36292"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36292" /></td>
      <td>AT36292</td>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I just can't work out what to change to uncheck all checkboxes if they are currently checked?

Comment: please check My answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use that top checkbox's state to determine if you should check or uncheck all. Like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.select-all').on('click', function() {
    var shouldCheck = $(this).is(":checked");
    $('table > tbody input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i, el) {
      $(el).prop('checked', shouldCheck);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th><input type="checkbox" class="select-all checkbox" name="select-all" /></th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Product ID</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Description</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="" id="85799">
      <td id="AT36288"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36288" /></td>
      <td>AT36288</td>
      <td>Apples</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85800">
      <td id="AT36289"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36289" /></td>
      <td>AT36289</td>
      <td>Bananas</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85801">
      <td id="AT36290"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36290" /></td>
      <td>AT36290</td>
      <td>Oranges</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85803">
      <td id="AT36292"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36292" /></td>
      <td>AT36292</td>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check whether or not the checkboxes are currently checked or not.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.select-all').on('click', function() {
    var values = []; // will contain all checkbox values that you can send via ajax
    $('table > tbody input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i, el) {
      
      
      // If checkboxes are currently checked, uncheck.
    
      if($(el).prop('checked')) $(el).prop('checked', false) 
      else $(el).prop('checked', true);



      values.push(el.value);
    });
    var productIDs = values.join();;
    // Create a reference to $(this) here:
    $this = $(this);
    $.post('productSelections.php', {
      type: 'updateSelections',
      productIDs: productIDs,
      selectionType: 'single'
    }, function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      if (data.error) {
        var ajaxError = (data.text);
        var errorAlert = 'There was an error updating the Product Selections Selections - ' + ajaxError;
        $this.closest('td').addClass("danger");
        //display AJAX error details
        $("#updateSelectionsErrorMessage").html(errorAlert);
        $("#updateSelectionsError").show();
        return; // stop executing this function any further
      } else {
        $this.closest('td').addClass("success")
        $this.closest('td').removeClass("danger");
      }

    }).fail(function(xhr) {
      var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
      var ajaxError = 'There was an error updating the Product Selections - AJAX request error. HTTP Status: ' + httpStatus + '. Please contact Apple Business Operations';
      $this.closest('td').addClass("danger");
      $("#updateSelectionsErrorMessage").html(ajaxError);
      $("#updateSelectionsError").show();
      $this.attr('checked', false); // Unchecks it
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th><input type="checkbox" class="select-all checkbox" name="select-all" /></th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Product ID</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Description</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="" id="85799">
      <td id="AT36288"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36288" /></td>
      <td>AT36288</td>
      <td>Apples</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85800">
      <td id="AT36289"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36289" /></td>
      <td>AT36289</td>
      <td>Bananas</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85801">
      <td id="AT36290"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36290" /></td>
      <td>AT36290</td>
      <td>Oranges</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85803">
      <td id="AT36292"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36292" /></td>
      <td>AT36292</td>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This _toggles_ all checkboxes, though. If you check one and then click the one in the title, it will check all checkboxes, but __uncheck__ the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code i think its as per your requirements.
If You check All all sub-checkbox selected if you uncheck any subcheckbox then its Select-all checkbox uncheck.

```js
       $('.select-all').on('click', function () {
              
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $('.select-item').prop('checked', this.checked);
                  
                } else {

                    $(".select-item").removeAttr('checked');
                    $(".select-all").removeAttr('checked');
                  
                }
                  });
$('.select-item').on('click', function () {
            if ($('.select-item:checked').length === $('.select-item').length) {
                $(".select-all").prop('checked', true);
            
            }
            var s = $(this).is(":checked");
            if (s === false) {
                $(".select-all").removeAttr('checked');
               
            }});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th><input type="checkbox" class="select-all checkbox" name="select-all" /></th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Product ID</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Description</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="" id="85799">
      <td id="AT36288"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36288" /></td>
      <td>AT36288</td>
      <td>Apples</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85800">
      <td id="AT36289"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36289" /></td>
      <td>AT36289</td>
      <td>Bananas</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85801">
      <td id="AT36290"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36290" /></td>
      <td>AT36290</td>
      <td>Oranges</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="85803">
      <td id="AT36292"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="AT36292" /></td>
      <td>AT36292</td>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @user982124 Please Check My answer its as per your Requirements

Comment: Okay Got The Point :)